# Does apache Alias also work with mod_vhost_alias variables?

Tags: apache, alias, virtualhost

I'm using mod_vhost_alias for Apache to dynamically use vhosts and documentroots which works fine... But now I'm trying to add an alias to another directory somewhere within the dynamic allocated directories but I can't get it to work...

This is what I have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName project.dev.testdomain.com
    ServerAlias *.project.dev.testdomain.com

    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot /home/%-5/www/%-4/subdir/httpdocs



    Alias /images/ "/home/%-5/www/%-4/subdir/latest/images/"
</VirtualHost>
```

In error log it just shows: File does not exist: /home/%-5

Please advise...

Comment: Tried it without quotes as well... No luck...

Comment: Hey ho, I'm kind of having a similar issue. Did you make any progress on the topic?

Comment: Sorry but no, I got stuck doing other stuff and I moved away from Apache to Nginx altogether :S This is as far as I got back then...